# Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction. Works on devnet but not mainnet

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js

I am trying to make a spl-token transfer from a user wallet. The code below works perfectly on the devnet but throws `Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction` . It creates an associated token account but fails on instruction.

How would the program id be incorrect if solana's token program id never changes?

```
let mint = new web3.PublicKey(mintAccount)
let toWallet = new web3.PublicKey("ADDRESS")
let owner = new web3.PublicKey(fromWallet.publicKey)
const createTransaction = async (mint, minerWallet, owner) => {

  const transaction = new web3.Transaction()
 
  const destinationAccount = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    mint,
    toWallet,
    false
  )

  const sourceAccount = await splToken.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    mint,
    owner,
    false
  )

  console.log("sending from " + sourceAccount.toBase58() + "to " + destinationAccount.toBase58())

  transaction.feePayer = fromWallet.publicKey

  let blockhashObj = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
  transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhashObj.blockhash;
  
  let signature = '';
try {
   
    const destinationAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(destinationAccount)
    const destTokenAccountMissing = !destinationAccountInfo
    if (destTokenAccountMissing) {
      console.log("creating token account cuz it needs one")
      transaction.add(
        splToken.Token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
          splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always associated token program id
          splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // always token program id
          mint, // mint (which we used to calculate ata)
          destinationAccount, // the ata we calcualted early
          toWallet, // token account owner (which we used to calculate ata)
          fromWallet.publicKey // payer, fund account, like SystemProgram.createAccount's from
        )
      );
    }

  transaction.add(
      splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        sourceAccount,
        destinationAccount,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        [],
        1
      )
    )
    
  signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
  console.log('info', 'Transaction sent:', signature)

  await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');
  console.log('success', 'Transaction successful!', signature);
  return true
  
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error', `Transaction failed! ${error?.message}`, signature);
  return false
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IncorrectProgramId` from the token program means that the owner of the account wasn't the expected spl-token program.

In your case, it might be that `sourceAccount` hasn't been created on mainnet yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the program id in your `lib.rs` (if you're using Anchor) is correct, and that this program id matches the one provided in Anchor.toml.

Also print the program-id in your provider to cross-check that your Typescript frontend actually uses the right program.

If you use the anchor framework, you can get the program-idea (to be inserted in all the spots mentioned above!), by running `solana-address -k target/deploy/program-keypair.json` from within the directory where your `Anchor.toml` is stored.